# How to get ALL available properties for a DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a reference to a user object, the `Properties` collection of this object will only contain properties that have values set but I need to check if a property (by name) exists for this object - I guess this would come from the schema.

I have looked at `deUser.SchemaEntry`, but I can't find any useful property info from this object.

Any ideas?

```
DirectoryEntry deUser = new DirectoryEntry(path);

foreach (var prop in deUser.Properties)
{
   //if user.Properties["company"] is not set on this user then 
   //it will not be available here although 'company' is 
   //a property defined for the user class
}

//How do I get to the list of all available properties using 
//deUserSchema as below
DirectoryEntry deUserSchema = deUser.SchemaEntry();
```

Comment: could you post the code you describe in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be easier to solve than it appeared. In each object (DirectoryEntry) in AD there are dynamic properties named `allowedAttributes` and `allowedAttributesEffective`.

On standard retrieval by de.Attributes [], returns `null`. You must first force the rebuild of the object cache (`de.RefreshCache`) with these parameters.
My code:

```
public static List<string> AllAvailableProperties(this DirectoryEntry de)
{
      de.RefreshCache(new string[] { "allowedAttributes" });
      return de.Properties["allowedAttributes"].AsStringList();
}
```

If we want a list of attributes for a class, we should take any object (existing) of this class.

Answer (score 0):

To list all properties try this :

```
foreach (var name in deUser.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: That will return only property names that have values set but not the others - that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.schemaentry(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use `DirectoryEntry.SchemaEntry` to retrieve all attributes.

> An entry's schema determines a list of its mandatory and optional property names.
>   You can use this property to find out what properties and methods are available on the associated object.

```
String myADSPath = "LDAP://onecity/CN=Users,DC=onecity,DC=corp,DC=fabrikam,DC=com";

// Creates an Instance of DirectoryEntry.
DirectoryEntry  myDirectoryEntry=new DirectoryEntry(myADSPath, UserName, SecurelyStoredPassword);

// Gets the SchemaEntry of the ADS object.
DirectoryEntry mySchemaEntry = myDirectoryEntry.SchemaEntry;

if (string.Compare(mySchemaEntry.Name,"container") == 0)
{
   foreach(DirectoryEntry myChildDirectoryEntry in myDirectoryEntry.Children)
   {
       //...do what you need
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - your 'myADSPath' appears to point to some 'Users' container, is this the Users OU or the Users schema entry path?

Comment: If I use an actual user path for myADSPath then , mySchemaEntry.Name will be 'user' and then obviously myDirectoryEntry will have no children. I think there are some problems with this code...

Comment: @A_L, I'm not in a position to test this code, but try using `Directory Searcher`. Something like this. `DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry); search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("*"); search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("+"); ` and use `SearchResult` to loop through those properties. Let me know if that helps.